# SQL Server 2008 : recursive query

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have this query

```
Select distinct 
   patient.id as Patient_ID
from 
   patient 
inner join 
   ......
where 
    incident.completionDate Between Convert(smalldatetime, '01/02/2015', 103) and Convert(smalldatetime, '04/03/2015', 103)
```

and I want to make it recursive running from a start date till today.

I tried like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(--gets you data from 01/01/2014 till current date
    SELECT  
        patient.id as Patient_ID, 
        Convert(smalldatetime, '01/01/2014', 103) start 
    FROM 
        patient 
    INNER JOIN
        .......
    WHERE 
        incident.completionDate Between Convert(smalldatetime, '01/01/2014', 103) and Convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE(), 103)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  
        incident.Patient_ID, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,start))-1), DATEADD(mm, 1, start)), 103) start
    FROM 
        cte incident 
    WHERE 
        incident.Patient_ID Between CONVERT(smalldatetime, DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, start)) - 1), DATEADD(mm, 1, start)), 103) and Convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE(), 103)
    and CONVERT(smalldatetime,DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,start))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,start)),103) <= Convert(smalldatetime, GETDATE(), 103)
)
select * 
from cte
```

but now I'm getting an error:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column
>   "start" of recursive query "CTE".

Can you help me with the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

The column `start` is a `smalldatetime` in the anchor part and a `varchar(25)` in the recursive part. They have to be the same types as the error says.

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column
>   "start" of recursive query "CTE".